# Notepad++ Recording a Macro with searches in it

Tags: notepad++, macros

I'm using Notepad++ to edit a calendar ".ics" file.
I've used simply macros before but can't get this one to work.

I need to find the text "cancelled", then go back 6 rows (ok so far).
Then I need to start a 'selection', search for "end:vevent" then delete the selected text.

I can't see how to start a selection before the find.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1817721/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: workaround: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/23529/selecting-text-while-doing-a-search-in-a-macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick for such problems is to use the menu command
*Edit > Begin/End Select (Ctrl+Shift+B)*.

The procedure to record should be similar to this :

- Find "cancelled"
- Go back 6 rows
- Issue Ctrl+Shift+B
- Search for "end:vevent"
- Issue another Ctrl+Shift+B. The text between those two will be selected.
- Issue Del to delete.

The final macro will probably need some tweaking to correctly position
the cursor for the two selection points.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Thank you, worked a treat.

Comment: Done and thank you again.